# How to store an Image into a "global" variable

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

I have:

```
var current_image_;
var canvas_;

canvas_ = new fabric.Canvas('myid');
canvas_.renderOnAddRemove = false;


function LoadImage(path)
{
    fabric.Image.fromURL(path, function(oImg) {
        // Something
        current_image_ = oImg;
 });    

    Draw();
}

// Other things

function Draw()
{
    canvas_.clear();
    canvas_.add(current_image_);
    canvas_.renderAll();
}
```

`current_image_` is Always a null reference. Why? In fact it doesn't render anything.
I just want to try to render in certain times the Whole scene, but I felt in error.

Thanks!

Comment: Move your call to "Draw" **inside** the callback to `.fromURL()`.

Comment: @Pointy it works, but I don't understand why!

Comment: @misiMe read the linked duplicates - that `.fromURL()` call is **asynchronous**. The call returns immediately, before the HTTP request completes. The callback is called *after* it completes, so at that point the image is ready.